# Convert the result of a NSFetchedResultsController into a NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I do a NSFetchedResultsController to fill a tableView with an quick alphabet index on the side.That works fine, but I would like to implement a search function made by another developer, and this search function need for input a basic NSArray (it used to works whith the result of a simple NSFetchRequest). So how is it possible to make this conversion ?

here is the request part:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"domaine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"nom_court" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"nom_court" cacheName:@"root"];
[fetchRequest release];
NSError *error;

//BOOL success = [controller performFetch:&error];
[fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are happy with the answer can you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: oups, I'm sorry I intend ot do it, but lack of time I cannot try it out properly...but i guess it works so you get my vote :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call `NSArray *fetchedObjects = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];` after your `performFetch:` method has been called